# How to get Fully Qualified Name of a Type using Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection, datamodel

I have a scenario where I need to check whether a DataContext of a control is implementing "INotifyPropertyChanged" and another interface called "ITObject". The interface "ITObject" is located in some other assembly and the implementing class is called "TObjectBase" which has an event called "TObjectChanged".

We do not add their assemblies to our project but instead they will be adding our assemblies to their projects which we build and give them.

The problem I have is that the only information I have is the textual representation of these class/interface names and nothing more but I need to check at runtime whether the DataContext of the control is implementing these interfaces and hook to the TObjectChanged event and react to it.

I tried using Type.GetType("TObjectBase") to check it, but I require the fully qualified name, isn't it? because they are all located in a different assembly that I don't have any idea of. Also, IsAssignableFrom("ITObject") also fails.

I was wondering if the userbase here could help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a type implements an interface with C# reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load all the active assemblies in the app domain, then walk each assembly's types looking for a name match. Without the assembly name though, you can't use `Type.GetType()` as you saw.

The following simple program works for me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetFqTypeName("IMyInterface"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static String GetFqTypeName(string shortTypeName)
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .ToList()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => x.Name == shortTypeName)
            .Select(x => x.FullName)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `is` operator.

```
if (DataContext is INotifyPropertyChanged && DataContext is ITObject)
{
   // magic
}
```

You also have `IsAssignableFrom` backwards.

```
typeof(ITObject).IsAssignableFrom(DataContext.GetType());
```

Comment: That doesn't really workout. I don't have a reference to it and the only thing I know about its name is the textual representation.
`code
if(currentDataContext is Type.GetType("ITObject"))
{
// Functionality
}
`
doesn't work either ...

Comment: I thought you said you had a reference to the type `ITObject`?

Comment: No, I do not have the reference of the ITObject as we do not add their assemblies to our projects. Please see my below post on how I am trying to achieve it :) 

PS: I am unable to post code in my comments, so I posted as a separate reply instead