# Resolve type of generic T to a specific interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics, types

I want to find the type of the generic `T` and compare that to check which interface it is, at run-time.

So, this works for finding the type of T at run-time :

```
Type interfaceName = typeof(T); // gives me the specific interface type
```

But when I try to check if it is equal to the type of an interface, I am not getting the expected response.

```
Type.GetType("IMyInterface"); //this returns null
```

How do I compare these two?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection

Comment: @TryingToImprove That's not what I was looking for. Besides, I didn't want to use Reflection in this part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Type.GetType`, you need to pass the [assembly-qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, it looks like you just want to check the name of an interface, so you can simply use

```
Type interfaceType = typeof(T);
string interfaceName = interfaceType.Name;
```

You can also simply check to see if `typeof(T) == typeof(IMyInterface)`

Comment: "simply check to see if typeof(T) == typeof(IMyInterface)" would be the correct answer all by itself.

Comment: The first solution would result in false positives if there were an interface with the same name elsewhere.  The second solution wouldn't pass if the type is some type that implements or extends the interface.

Comment: @Servy Fair point on the first solution, it's a straightforward fix to the original post. But with regards to the second, the question states *"I want to find the type of the generic T and compare that to check **which interface it is**, at run-time."* - not which interface it implements or extends.

Comment: @AlexG Do you think he really means that or, do you think he didn't know the correct terminology to explain what he really wanted?

Comment: @Servy I wouldn't presume to know; if that is the case then the question can be closed as a duplicate of the one linked by TryingToImprove

Comment: @Servy : Alex read it right. I wanted to check the Interface type itself.

Comment: @Servy Oh and by the way, this is she, not he. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1):

`GetType` method expects a *fully qualified* name. So you need either:

```
Type.GetType("YourNamespace.IMyInterface");
```

or if you have a reference to the assembly where `IMyInterface` is declared then just `typeof(IMyInterface)` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
typeof(T).Name == "IMyInterface"
```