# How can I know if a propertyInfo is of the type IList in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

Given this class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public IList<AnotherClass> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

And this code:

```
SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();

PropertyInfo[] properties = myClass.GetType().GetProperties();
for(int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
{
    //How can I figure that the current property is a collection/list?
}
```

Things I've tried:

```
bool a1 = properties[i].PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList));
//false
bool a2 = properties[i].PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<>));
//false
bool a3 = typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(properties[i].PropertyType);
//false
bool a4 = typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(properties[i].PropertyType);
//false
bool a5 = properties[i].PropertyType.Equals(typeof(IList));
//false
bool a6 = properties[i].PropertyType.Equals(typeof(IList<>));
//false
bool a7 = properties[i].PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IList));
//false
bool a8 = properties[i].PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IList<>));
//false
bool a9 = properties[i].PropertyType is IList;
//false
bool a0 = typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(properties[i].PropertyType);
//false
```

Plus all of the above with `PropertyType.GetType()`. How can I figure this out?

Comment: I'd note that you're using `IsAssignableFrom` backwards [DotNetFiddleExample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VgD6n) in some of your examples.

Comment: `a3` should have returned true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if(properties[i].PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
   properties[i].PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
```

This will return *true* for all `IList<>` types.If you wanna check for others, (`ICollection`, `IEnumerable` etc.) you can do the same check for them as well.

Comment: but this will fail, imo, on the class with different properties. `GetGenericTypeDefinition(..)` can be called only on generic type properties, on other will raise an exception. Need a security check.

Comment: @Tigran you are right thanks for pointing that out. I have added the check to make sure the type is generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **System.Collection.IList** variant:

```
        public static bool IsIList(this Type type)
        {
            return type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(System.Collections.IList));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine("Is IList:" + (new List()).GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)));

From this question: [How to determine if a type implements an interface with C# reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection)