# How to determine dynamically if type is an Interface using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

For starters, this question is **not** a repeat of this post that I have read 100 times (please read on for question): [How to determine if a type implements an interface with C# reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection)

I'm using reflection to iterate through properties on objects dynamically at runtime to manipulate and add data. The root issue for me is naturally, you *cannot* instantiate an instance of an `Interface` and therefore my code using `Activator.CreateInstance` later downstream **must not** be ran against types found to be an `Interface` or a collection of an `Interface` type.

Say I have the following on an `Person` class:

`public IList<Address> addresses1 {get ; set; } \\ This property **should** flag being an Interface
public List<Address> addresses2 {get ; set; } \\ This property **should NOT** flag being an Interface`

Using the following code while reflecting on the property I *can* find out if the property implements an `Interface`:

`propertyTypeFromReflection.GetInterfaces().Any()`

The problem I have is both `IList<Address>` and `List<Address>` have the statement above return `true`. That's because even `List<T>` as we know actually implements a slew of Interfaces (i.e. `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, etc.).

Since I am doing this investigation dynamically, I have no idea of how to test if my type implements a *specific* `Interface` like *all* the examples show such as the link I posted at the beginning which do the following:

`typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyType))`
`typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface))`

I need help determining if the object Property reflected upon dynamically and in focus, is **directly** an Interface as opposed to a concrete type? All the examples require testing the known `Interface` to a known concrete type, but since this is happening dynamically I don't know how to accomplish this?

Comment: [`Type.IsInterface` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinterface%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @SLaks - Appreciate your quality assistance. It certainly helped me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Type.IsInterface` Property 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinterface(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Case of can't see the forest through the trees - this worked perfectly. In my very working man's knowledge of C# reflection I obviously missed this.