# how to check if IQueryable<T>.ElementType is Iterface

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, iqueryable

My (EF db first) type sits behind interface `IPolicyNumber`. I get `IQueryable<T>` and want to check what I got is correct type (does this table is searchable by that column which is determined by having that interface). Currently I am using `typeof(IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` which is a bit old school, I was wondering if there was a way to use something like:

`IQueryable<T>.ElementType is IPolicyNumber`

Full method is below:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
    {
        if (search != null && search.PolicyNumber.HasValue && typeof(IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
           queryable = queryable.SearchByPolicyNumber(search);
        }

        return queryable;
    }

public static IQueryable<IPolicyNumber> SearchByPolicyNumber<IPolicyNumber>(this IQueryable<IPolicyNumber> queryable, SearchModel search)
    {
        var policyNumberParameterLambda = Expression.Parameter((typeof(IPolicyNumber)));
        var policyNumberColumnLambda = Expression.Property(policyNumberParameterLambda, "POLICY_NO");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IPolicyNumber, bool>>(
          Expression.Equal(policyNumberColumnLambda,
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(search.PolicyNumber), policyNumberColumnLambda.Type)
          ), policyNumberParameterLambda);
        return queryable.Where(lambda);
    }
```

Comment: No, basically; `IQueryable<T>.ElementType is IPolicyNumber` asks whether the `Type` object (`RuntimeTypeInfo`, most likely) implements `IPolicyNumber`, which it never will

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi Mark, is there a way to `IQueryable<T>.ElementType something something(IPolicyNumber)` that would return true? :)

Comment: absolutely! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection

Comment: @MarcGravell so `IQueryable<T>.ElementType` is pretty useless then checking for inheritance then isn't it?

Comment: not really, no; it should work fine

Comment: @MarcGravell `typeof(IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType)` does work indeed, wanna paste it as answer? :)

Comment: frankly, I prefer the `typeof(T)` code in the question :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I suppose it probably runs `typeof(T)` in IQueryable anyway, I somehow noticed `IQueryable<T>.ElementType` property only now, and to me it's a new 'shiny' :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax to match interface to type while using `IQueryable<T>.ElementType` would be following:

`typeof(IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType)`