# List of Types that implement an interface or base class

Tags: c#, list, types, interface, base-class

How would I go about defining a List of Types (`List<Type>`) where I want to restrict the Types in this list to types that implement an interface or a base class?

For a very simplified example of what I want to achieve, I have an abstract class `Foo` with many different child classes `FooA`, `FooB`, `FooC`, `FooD`, etc. I then have another class `BarAD` that has a list of permitted `Foo` types (`FooA` and `FooD`) for some operations. Something like the following would then take place:

```
public class BarAD
{
    private List<Type> fooTypes;

    public BarAD()
    {
        fooTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(FooA), typeof(FooD) };
    }

    public void Execute(Foo obj)
    {
        foreach (var fooType in fooTypes)
        {
            if (obj is fooType)
                obj.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

The way it currently works, I can use any type in my list. Some method could add String or Integer as types in the list and the code would compile and run fine, which makes my life a little more complicated down the road. Which brings me back to the question: any way to restrict my `List<Type>` to only accept Types that are children of the `Foo` class?

Comment: You can not restrict this at compile time. `Type` is a .NET class and is it applicable to all the types. You can restrict is at runtime though by using reflection. [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection)

Comment: You're looking for `IsAssignableFrom` on the type `Type`.

Comment: @Enigmativity How would I use that to do what I need?

Comment: @SushiYetiDev - Something like `var derived = this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToList();`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use generic constraint.

```
public class BarAD
{
    private List<Type> Types = new List<Type>();

    public void Add<T>() where T : Foo
    {
        Types.Add( typeof( T ) );
    }
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{
    BarAD bar = new BarAD();
    bar.Add<FooA>();
    bar.Add<FooD>();
}
```

Although I feel it's kind of strange. Usually I'd like to utilize polymorphism instead of types.

Comment: I agree with the feeling. I also find it very strange, yet I don't see a better way to achieve what I am looking to do. The reason for this is that it's part of a procedural algorithm and we need to be able to save its results.
I will keep your suggestion in mind and will try it out but I don't think it will be able to do what I want it to do.

Comment: This does not answer the question: "any way to restrict my `List<Type>` to only accept Types that are children of the `Foo` class?"